# Switched MySQL to Postgres: "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Switching a rails app from MySQL to Postgres gives the following error:

```
ERROR: column "contacts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Here is the scope in question:

```
class User < MyModel
  def self.top_contacts(timeframe = 1.week.ago, limit = 5)
    Contact.unscoped
          .where('created_at between ? and ?', timeframe, Time.now)
          .group(:user_id)
          .order('sum(score) DESC')
          .limit(limit)
          .includes(:user)
          .collect{|x| x.user}
  end
end
```

1. How to fix this?
2. Isn't using Rails as the database abstraction layer ensure switching the database should work seamlessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the level of the SQL, which is invisible from your ORM layer. The problem is exactly with the RoR ORM, because it seems to generate a MySQL-friendly query which uses an extraordinary feature of the MySQL, which postgresql don't have.

The quick solution: give `contacts.id` to the columns by which you are GROUP-ing as well:

```
.group("user_id, contacts.id");
```

Comment: Is there is a more permanent solution that can be done in one place (like a config maybe) or changing all queries to do this is the only way?

Comment: @user3188544 Thanks! RoR had to have some flag or settings about the used SQL dialect. It could be a way. Another way could be if you selected only the actual column, or you used aggregated queries (for example, `MIN(columnname) as columnname`).